# Speed up position check for embedded length on stream

Tags: c#, performance

I received help with adding the length of a stream in the first 4 bytes, meaning it's there as an `int`.

I am adding it at the start and sending it, while the receiving part checks for its position.

However, the position checking is a bit slow, so I wonder if it's possible to improve it.  Maybe using unsafe pointers or something, but I'm not sure.

```
currentPosition = 0;
while (currentPosition < sizeof(int) && tt1.Connected)
{
    currentPosition += tt1.GetStream().Read(lenArray, currentPosition, sizeof(int) - currentPosition);
}
```

There is the example on what it does at the end of the receiving part.  It goes through it, and it's a bit slow.

I can't see much of what can be done here, but hopefully someone else has a better idea.

Here is the whole code, which may help show how it functions:

```
tempBytes = new byte[length];
ms = new MemoryStream(tempBytes);

int currentPosition = 0;

while (currentPosition < length && tt1.Connected)
{
    currentPosition += tt1.GetStream().Read(tempBytes, currentPosition, length - currentPosition);
}

newImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

gmp.DrawImage(newImage, 0, 0);

currentPosition = 0;
while (currentPosition < sizeof(int) && tt1.Connected)
{
    currentPosition += tt1.GetStream().Read(lenArray, currentPosition, sizeof(int) - currentPosition);
}
length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lenArray, 0);
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to open a `BinaryReader` on that stream? It'll take care of most of what you're looking for.

Comment: The reason is, i want to improve the speed over BinaryReader/Writer, in this case (i only send images). So trying everything there is:)

Comment: Are you sure the length reading is what's slowing down your code? I think it's much more likely that it's reading from disk/network/whatever that's slowing you down and there's not much you can do about that.

Comment: Yes and no. It´s not Slowing it down, but it´s what takes up the most time Except the reading.  For reading the data takes about 24ms in this scenario, and the count thing, takes 6-9ms. Not much, but it adds up. And i am trying to improve latency by any means. Thanks

Comment: why does your last while loop go from `currentPosition` to `sizof(int)`? could you change that value to something smaller?

Comment: Not sure right of the bat since i changed it a bit now. But i think it has to do with that the information it stored in the first 4 byte (size of int32) hence why i use it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that it's not likely to be your position checking code that's slowing you down.  Maybe you could squeeze some performance out with unsafe code, but that's maybe saving a copy from one buffer to another.  It would be nice to put that reading loop into a separate function, something like:

```
byte[] ReadBytes(SomeType tt1, int bytesToRead);
```

I can't guess what type `tt1` is, but is it possible that retrieving the value for `Connected` is slow?  What about `GetStream`?